# What's causing this ringing? GaN SEPIC Converter Gate Ringing

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, sepic, gan

I'm designing a SEPIC converter using a HEMT GaN from EPC (EPC2204) and a dedicated GaN driver IC (1EDN71x6U). I've been in this loop (mind the pun) trying to mitigate gate ringing, and I'm having a tough time minimising a huge voltage sag when the gate turns on, and I'm finding this is leading to efficiency issues on the converter.

I've made an effort to reduce the switching node loop as much as possible and have made the traces as short as possible. I'm at a loss as to what's causing this deformity in the gate drive. The below trace has a 1ohm Rg value. The one below that, has a 10ohm gate resistor.

[image]
[image]

And below are some pictures of the schematic and PCB layout for these components. The gate drive path is all of 2mm

[image]

What are the options to better understand and diagnose this, this is the list I have at the moment:

- Play with Rg values to slow turnon rate
- Try a negative gate bias
- Ferrite bead on the gate
- Increase gate trace width
- Snubber on the gate?

I'm using a high frequency probe with a short ground clip to acquire signals.

[image]

Comment: I first took the initial ring time, which is close to 8 ns in both images, and grabbed the input cap from the EPC2204 datasheet and came up with `(8e-9 s)^2/700e-12 farad` or about 10 uH. Looking at the schematic there I see a 15 uH inductor. I don't have an answer, and I'm assuming you connect up your scope as well as anyone, but the coincidence of just happening to find the size inductor I would be looking for does bother me. I'd change it to see if the initial ring period shifts with it. If so, the R of 10 rather than 1 may just allow it to swing more. I'm ignorant, though.

Comment: Please show your probe setup.

Comment: What bandwidth is the scope/probe? Beware that GaN is so fast, a scope of 1GHz+ bandwidth may be required to fully resolve the waveforms. Where is the nearest (+5V?) bypass other than C19? What are [unlabeled] (100m shunt resistors)?